# How can i yarn generate to use vue2-datepicker in nuxt to server production

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

this is my nuxt.config on localhost can use beautiful datepicker

```
 export default {
  css: [
  ],

  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/date-time.js', mode: 'client'},
  ],

  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxt-hero-icons/outline/nuxt',
  ],

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
  ],

  bootstrapVue: {
    componentPlugins: [
      'LayoutPlugin',
      'FormPlugin',
      'FormCheckboxPlugin',
      'FormInputPlugin',
      'FormRadioPlugin',
      'ToastPlugin',
      'ModalPlugin'
    ],
    directivePlugins: ['VBPopoverPlugin', 'VBTooltipPlugin', 'VBScrollspyPlugin']
  },

  build: {
  }
}
```

this on my production server

[image: this on my production server]

i try  `{ src: '~/plugins/date-time.js',mode: 'server'},` it not working

this is on Deploy Script `yarn install && yarn generate`

Do I have to go and set up build somewhere else?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure to fully understand the issue here. Is it working locally and only broken on production? If you're using the `target: 'server'` (default) as it look like from your `nuxt.config.js` file, you need to run `yarn build` and not `yarn generate`. `yarn generate` is for SSG aka `target: 'static'`.

Comment: Also, you probably want your datepicker to work on both sides, so you should probably write `{ src: '~/plugins/date-time.js' }` and let it be on both. What is the exact name of the package?